# Why does Python return an escaping backslash in a string?

Tags: python, string, syntax, escaping

```
'\"atg is a codon, isn\'t it?\" \"Yes, it is\", he answered'
```

gives as output:

```
'"atg is a codon, isn\'t it?" "Yes, it is", he answered'
```

Why is the escape character showing up in the output?

When I type the string below, this doesn't happen.

```
'This is a codon, isn\'t it?'
```

The output I get is this:

```
"This is a codon, isn't it?"
```

Answer (score 2):

because in first one the whole string is in one-quote so another one-quotes should be escaped. Whereas in second one the whole string is in double quote.

```
>>> '\"atg is a codon, isn\'t it?\" \"Yes, it is\", he answered'
'"atg is a codon, isn\'t it?" "Yes, it is", he answered'
^                                                      ^
>>> 
>>> 'This is a codon, isn\'t it?'
"This is a codon, isn't it?"  # there is no need to escape the one-quote between double-quotes         
^                          ^
```

Comment: sorry, I don't get it: both strings are enclosed by single quotes. If I don't escape the one-quote between the double-quotes, I get a syntax error.

Comment: @oaklander114 Yes, but python changes them for a better representation. It's all about that, other wise there is no difference between these quotes for encapsulating the strings.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to avoid this besides using the print function?

Comment: @oaklander114 Yes, and I think there is no need for that at all, only for a custom representation you can manually use proper quotes to get the expected output, sometimes 1, 2 or even 3 quote.

Answer (score 0):

The escape character is needed because that is the string that, if typed out exactly, would reproduce the string. The string contains both single and double quotes, so whichever type encloses the string will need to be escaped within the string.

Answer (score 0):

You get to choose either single quotes or double quotes to enclose a string.  Any occurrences of your enclosing quote character must be escaped with a '\'.

```
>>> b = 'Hello\'s'
>>> a = "Hello's"
>>> b = 'Hello\'s'
>>> c = 'Hello"s'
>>> d = "Hello\"s"
>>> a
"Hello's"
>>> b
"Hello's"
>>> c
'Hello"s'
>>> d
'Hello"s'
>>>
```

Comment: the odd (to me at least) behavior arises when you use both types of quotes within the string. For example `e = "\"Hello\'s\""` .In that case the escaping backslash shows up in the output.

Comment: That is weird.  At first I though it was because the the string is double quoted but if you do ```f="Hello\'s"``` you get expected behavior,  I wonder if it is a bug.

Comment: Its only a display issue in the REPL shell.  The string length is correct as is the position of the characters.